# How to ignoring subfolders in git

Tags: git

I would like to gitignore a sub folders inside a folder. 
Here is my current directory structure.

```
var
  www
    repo_name
      .gitignore
      README.md
      vendors
        vendor_a
        vendor_b
        vendor_c
```

I would like to ignore everything inside the folder `vendors` but when I write this rule inside my `.gitignore` it ignores the `vendors` folder itself.

```
#.gitignore
repo_name/vendors/
```

But the above rule ignores the folder `vendors` which is not what I wanted.

Comment: It's not clear why you don't want to ignore the `vendors` subfolder. Do you mean you _only_ want to ignore what's in there currently?

Comment: @SteveL Yes. I mean, I want the `vendors` folder to show up, but nothing that is inside it.

Comment: @An_roid And what's the difference between ignoring a directory, and ignoring the directory's contents? Can you edit your question to show a concrete situation where you don't get the results you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ignore everything inside the folder `vendors`, git will have no record of that folder's existence, because git doesn't track folders except as a way of getting to tracked content within them. If you want to have that folder there in a new checkout, you have to either use a post-checkout hook to create it or (forcibly, with `git add -f`) track a placeholder file in it -- an empty `.gitignore`, perhaps.

A demonstration:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo a/ >.gitignore
$ mkdir a
$ touch a/.gitignore
$ touch a/vendor{1,2,3}
$ git add -f a/.gitignore
$ git add .
$ git ls-files
.gitignore
a/.gitignore
$ git check-ignore -v a/vendor1
.gitignore:1:a/ a/vendor1
```

Git only cares about that one file in `a/` and won't add any more from it unless you force it.

Comment: Nope. This option did not work. It enlisted every vendors in vendors folder

Comment: Please see the transcript I just added.  Can you show how you got the behavior you're describing? I don't see how to get that with the `.gitignore` contents you describe.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `*` at the end: `repo_name/vendors/*`